# Three.js shader error 1282

Tags: node.js, three.js, webgl, node-gyp

Receiving following when trying to render using three.js.

> THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error: 1282 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false
>   gl.getProgramInfoLog not linked.

I have gotten my project running on a Windows 10 laptop and now trying to get it running on a Windows Server 2012. I speculate that it might be due to the server not having a real GPU, but I am no OpenGL developer and it's all chinese to me. This is what the DXDIAG says:

> **Display Devices**
>
> ```
>       Card name: RDPUDD Chained DD
>    Manufacturer: 
>       Chip type: 
>        DAC type: 
>     Device Type: n/a
>      Device Key: Enum\ROOT\BASICRENDER
>  Display Memory: n/a    Dedicated Memory: n/a
>   Shared Memory: n/a
>    Current Mode: 1920 x 1080 (32 bit) (32Hz)
>     Driver Name:  Driver File Version:  ()
>  Driver Version: 
>     DDI Version: 9Ex
>  Feature Levels: 
>    Driver Model:  Graphics Preemption:   Compute Preemption:    Driver Attributes: Final Retail    Driver Date/Size: , 0 bytes
>     WHQL Logo'd: n/a
> WHQL Date Stamp: n/a   Device Identifier: {D7B71AF4-43CC-11CF-3921-F003ADC2CB35}
>       Vendor ID: 0x1414
>       Device ID: 0x008C
>       SubSys ID: 0x00000000
>     Revision ID: 0x0000  Driver Strong Name: 
>  Rank Of Driver: 
>     Video Accel: 
>     DXVA2 Modes: 
>   Deinterlace Caps: n/a
>    D3D9 Overlay: Not Supported
>         DXVA-HD: Not Supported
>    DDraw Status: Not Available
>      D3D Status: Enabled
>      AGP Status: Not Available
> ```

So the process is as usual to install node-gyp, which is risky business. That requires Visual C++ Build tools, which is installed on the server. Python 2.7 is installed and I've run the commands that are stated in the Installation section: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

Then I use headless gl to be able to create the WebGL context in Three.js. That requires d3dcompiler_47.dll, which is added to the system32 folder. https://github.com/stackgl/headless-gl

The thing is that the server is pretty locked.. I am not able to do *npm install* of modules due to self signed certificate, probably since I am not allowed to do jack on the server. Now I'm pretty much stuck.. I don't know if my error is due to some compiler not being installed, if a module needs to be installed on the server, if node-gyp is mocking with me or whatever. It's a complete mess. But the server do work on my own machine. Anyone that have encountered something like it and could point me in a direction? Would be greatful!

Comment: What is the error message from the shaderInfoLog/programInfoLog? When a shader doesn't compile usually three.js will spit out a much longer message before the one you posted

Comment: Nothing in the console before that. Just the regular stuff from threejs where it is warning about unsupported texture functions. Is it spitting out a log file or something?

Comment: Which Three.js version you are using?

Comment: @PradipShenolkar latest.

I will setup a local server and try to mirror the clients one, except that I will have permissions to do stuff. Will get back when I've done tests.

Comment: I found out this was due to certificate issues on the server. After I set it up on a server that I had full control over, everything worked fine. But the issue lied within ´npm install gl´ since I could not get past some https requests that I else could bypass by using http. We ended up taking another route that I'm happy we did. This was all messy and I do not recommend doing something like this on servers where you don't have full control.